# Ubuntu 17.10: How to set default screenshot location?

Tags: 17.10, screenshot

In Ubuntu 17.04, there was an option to save a screenshot to a specific location. I understand that it's now in /home by default. In Ubuntu 17.10 (I've found solutions for 17.04 only), is there a way to specify another location and make it permanent?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pomsky I tried setting "Use default value" to "OFF" in /org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory and specifying another folder but it still automatically saves to /home/MY_USERNAME/
I also tried gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory 'file:///home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop' but to no avail.

Comment: See the bug report (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642) in proposed duplicate's answer, it won't work. You'll have to set another keyboard shortcut for that as a workaround.